# Identify duplicates and assign similar index in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, duplicates

Suppose that I have a sample data set that can be generated using code below

```
# Sample DataFrame with duplicate rows
data = {'A': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2],
        'B': [4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5],
        'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In above dataframe I want to assign duplicate rows similar index. For index `0` would be assigned to rows `0`, `1` and `4`. Similarly index `1` would be assigned to rows `1`, `5` and `7`. Duplicates should be identified using only column `A` and `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby().ngroup`:

```
df.index = df.groupby(['A','B']).ngroup()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  4  1
1  2  5  2
0  1  4  3
2  3  6  4
0  1  4  5
1  2  5  6
2  3  6  7
1  2  5  8
```